# How to setup readonly collection property with backing field in EF Core 2.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am trying to create an entity class which will expose a related collection through a readonly property, like this:

```
public class MyEntity: Entity
{
    public int Id{ get; private set; }
    private IList<RelatedEntity> _relatedEntities = new List<RelatedEntity>();
    public IReadOnlyList<RelatedEntity> RelatedEntities => _relatedEntities.ToList().AsReadOnly();
}
```

The builder class looks like this:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyEntity> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x=>x.Id);
    builder.Property<IReadOnlyList<RelatedEntity>>("RelatedEntities")
        .HasField("_relatedEntities ")
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
}
```

It builds but crashes at runtime with the exception:

> InvalidOperationException: The specified field '_relatedEntities' of type 'IList' cannot be used for the property 'MyEntity.RelatedEntities ' of type 'IReadOnlyList'. Only backing fields of types that are assignable from the property type can be used.

Could you provide a working example how to deal with this issue ?

Comment: I don't have the means to test it right now, but knowing how EF works, perhaps just try changing your `_relatedEntities` field to `protected`?

Comment: No - I am not using proxies extension (they need to be added explicitly with nuget package). Without this, the properties, fields and constructors can be private, as they are handled internally via reflection.

Answer (score 8):

I ckeck this and it worked:

```
private readonly List<RelatedEntity> _relatedEntitys;
public IReadOnlyCollection<RelatedEntity> RelatedEntitys => _relatedEntitys;
```

And configuration must be like below:

```
    builder.HasMany(x => x.RelatedEntitys)
        .WithOne()
        .IsRequired()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.RelatedEntityId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Metadata
        .FindNavigation("RelatedEntitys")
        .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Answer (score 5):

EF core requires you to use concrete types for backing fields. You need to change your code to:

```
private readonly List<RelatedEntity> _relatedEntities = new List<RelatedEntity>();
public IReadOnlyList<RelatedEntity> RelatedEntities => _relatedEntities.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is loud and clear:

> IList is not assignable to IReadOnlyList

Changing the property type to the same type as the backing field will do the trick.

#### Update:

Because `IEnumerable<T>` is read-only by default, this would be your best bet I believe.

```cs
    public class MyEntity: Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }

        private readonly List<RelatedEntity> _relatedEntities = _collection.ToList().AsReadOnly();

        public IEnumerable<RelatedEntity> RelatedEntities => _relatedEntities;
    }
```

Update your fluent API as follows:

```cs
    builder.HasKey(x=>x.Id);
    builder.Metadata.FindNavigation("RelatedEntities")
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
```

Comment: I can see one problem: IList exposess Add method - which I wanted to avoid. I don't want the client code to have an illusion that something can be added to the collection.

The second problem for this approach (beacuse I tried it) is that I get an exception:

The property 'Entity.RelatedEntity' is of type 'IList<RelatedEntity>' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: I updated my answer @Marcin. Using an IEnumerable will not expose add since it's readonly by default.

Comment: Yes - this would work, but the exception stays the same:

The property 'MyEntity.Rooms' is of type 'IEnumerable<RelatedEntity>' which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: (and sorry for confusing - there is no _collection field or property in the class - I've corrected the question)

Comment: Did you change your fluent api to reflect a List<T> instead of IReadOnlyList<RelatedEntity> ?

Comment: Yes - of course. Event though I think it is not necessary due to the conventions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field). But I changed.

Comment: Use FindNavigation to find related entities. Updated my answer @Marcin

Comment: Are you sure it'll compile? The semicolon after ("RelatedEntities"); is clearly a mistake, but is there HasField method available?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. There isn't any. But as long as you keep to naming conventions EF will be able to find navigation property. (that might mean ditching the underscore)

Answer (score -1):

For EF Core 2, I believe the backing field must be of type `HashSet<T>` to be correctly recognized by the framework, so this should work:

```
public class MyEntity {
  private HashSet<RelatedEntity> _relatedEntities = new HashSet<RelatedEntity>();

  public IReadOnlyCollection<RelatedEntity> RelatedEntities => _relatedEntities;
}
```

See also https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/54840443/ef-core-one-to-many-relationships--icollection-or-hashset-